# Is there a way in React to execute only part of the render function multiple times, while the other part keeps going with initial execution?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a game in React. Basic description:
Sheep images are being 'fired' from the center of the screen and they are animated to move to the borders. If they reach it, you lose. If you click on them before, they disappear, and you continue. I have made everything, except the counter which counts how many sheeps you have clicked on.
Description code:

```
<MainComponent  // everything else inside it
  renders <Component creating background/>
          <Component creating sheep images
            renders array of sheep images, with onClick,onAnimationEnd and other props.
                    that array is made of lot of same StyledComponents, in a for loop.
                    every StyledComponent is one sheep image. 
          />
/>
```

Everything works as I would like. On page load sheeps start firing out of the middle (with specific delay and speed), when I click on them they desappear, when they reach border, game ends. BUT, I don't know how and where to add `<CountScoreComponent/>`. 
I have tried to put it to render in all of the above components, but it either doesn't update the score, or it updates it but only shows the final score on game end (I want it to change every time I click on a sheep image), or it updates the score and shows it, but then everything re-renders and the whole array of images is recreated and restarted.

So, I understand, that React first creates all components, and it creates the whole array of sheep images immediately. Depending on where I put it it also immediately creates `<CountScoreComponent/>` with its initial value. How can I update the state of that component (or its return value) dynamically, on every click, but so that at the same time the initial array animation keeps executing (without re-rendering and restarting)?

EDIT:
CODE:

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component {
render(){
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <CreateEnvironment />
            <SheepsStart />                      
        </React.Fragment>
        );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<MainComponent/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

sheepsStart.js

```
const animDuration = []; //gets populated with 100 random numbers
const positionLeft = []; //positions for KeyFrames, 100 numbers defined by external function call
const positionBottom = [];


export class SheepsStart extends React.Component { 
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {gameOver:false};
    this.handleAnimationEnd = this.handleAnimationEnd.bind(this);       
}   
handleAnimationEnd(){
    this.setState({gameOver:true});
}
render(){
    const arrayOfComponents = [];
    for (let index = 0;index<100;index++){
        if(this.state.gameOver === false){
    arrayOfComponents.push(<CreateSheeps src={sheep} alt={`sheep-${index}`} 
            style = {{animationDelay:`${index/2}s`}} left = {positionLeft[index]} bottom = {positionBottom[index]} 
            time = {animDuration[index]} onAnimationEnd = {this.handleAnimationEnd}/>);
        }
        else {
        alert("GAME OVER! ");
        break;
        }
    }
            return (
        <React.Fragment>                        
        {arrayOfComponents}                                 
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

}

createSheeps.js

```
export class CreateSheeps extends React.Component { 
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {left:this.props.left, bottom:this.props.bottom,    display:'inline'};
    this.handleClickAnimation = this.handleClickAnimation.bind(this);                 
}    
handleClickAnimation(){
    this.setState({display:'none'});
}     
render(){        
    const sheepWantsToEscape = keyframes`
    100% {
      left:${this.state.left}%;
      bottom:${this.state.bottom}%;
    }
    `        
    const CreateSheeps = styled.img`
    //some data
    `

    return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <CreateSheeps src = {this.props.src} style = {this.props.style} 
        onClick = {this.handleClickAnimation} onAnimationEnd = {this.props.onAnimationEnd}/>         
    </React.Fragment>   
    )  
}
```

}

Comment: Can you explain/demonstrate how your game state is handled?

Comment: `<Component creating sheep images/>` has state {gameOver:true/false}, which is changed with function onAnimationEnd (when sheep reaches predefined fromTheBorder percentage)

Comment: `<StyledComponent/>` has three state values: two of them for creating a random trajectory (those data are sent to Keyframes), and the third is for setting the display of the image to none , when image is clicked, which is connected to onClick event

Comment: or should I just simply put the whole code?

Comment: www.codesandbox.io/ is a good place to demonstrate you code easly

Comment: You can put your Images in own Components and try to prevent them from being rerendred. I'm not sure if this also works with css animation but [shouldComponentUpdate][1] is a good start - read the text, than you will understand why "PureComponent" is maybe your solution. 


  [1]: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: did you try [cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) in react? i dont know yet how it works but i think it's may be applicable in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element can be prevented from being re-rendered by moving it to separate component that prevents updates by using `shouldComponentUpdate` hook, `PureComponent` or `memo`. i.e.:

```
const ComponentThatIsRarelyUpdated = memo(props => <ComponentThatNeedsToBeRarelyUpdated {...props}/>;

...

<CountScoreComponent/>
<ComponentThatIsRarelyUpdated propThatTriggersAnUpdate={...} />
```

In this case this is XY problem. The actual problem is that the state of `ComponentThatNeedsToBeRarelyUpdated` is reset when it's re-rendered. It should be either stateful and preserve the state until it's unmounted, or the state should be [lifted up to parent component](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Most likely parent component should store the state for all sheeps.

Comment: Ok, but when I put the score into the parent state, and somehow connect it to the image onClick, when that click occurs, and after that setState changes the parent state, it will re-render the whole parent render function , right?

Comment: So , it will eventually re-render the array of images , which I do not want?

Comment: That's correct. A parent needs to be rerendered any way. The goal is to not affect children with parent component rerender. This can be achieved by either preventing children from being rerendered when a parent rerenders, or by moving a state to parent, so children can be rerendered any time. That's what the answer suggests. That's what It's unclear what your sheep components look like from the pseudocode you posted. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would really help to give more specific advice about what needs to be changed.

Comment: I`ll put some code in question. Please stand by for a few minutes.

Comment: From what I see, `ComponentThatNeedsToBeRarelyUpdated` is `CreateSheeps`, it needs to be wrapped with ComponentThatIsRarelyUpdated. Moving the whole state (sheep positions) to a parent is not an option if you rely on CSS animations for game logic (you will likely need to change this to programmatic animations if you're serious about this app). CreateSheeps needs to accept a callback to update a parent when it's clicked.

Comment: what do you consider 'being serious about app'?

Comment: I mean not just React exercise but real game that will be played by someone. There may be problems with developing it further with such design constraints.